# Understanding Java constructors

Tags: java, android, constructor, compiler-errors

How do I avoid this compilation error:

> The constructor BasicNameValuePair(String, Float) is undefined

for code like this:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Zam_sum",
                    Float.valueOf(zam.getSum())));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition the default Constructor takes a String name and a String value.

```
BasicNameValuePair(String name, String value)
```

Try this:

```
String zamSum = zam.getSum().toString();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Zam_sum", zamSum);
```